# Story about a brain that leaves human, starts orbiting earth and gains consciousness

Tags: story-identification

The book is about a brain which leaves a dying man (not sure if he was dying) and then starts orbiting earth. It observes events on Earth and gains consciousness. I heard about it last year, but I'm unable to recall its name. It's a postmodern science fiction book and the writer isn't very famous.

Comment: Some possible aspects of the [Bobiverse](http://dennisetaylor.org/legion/)

Comment: Or Plus by Joseph McElroy

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is indeed Plus by Joseph McElroy. Dang, my description was so off.

Comment: @no1name Please remember to accept the answer posted by Ayshe. See [help] for more information.

Answer (score 3):

[*Plus*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00TEG914M) by Joseph McElroy

> A brain orbiting the earth in a capsule, its human body gone, its
>   onetime body. A novel written from the point of view of the brain told
>   in the 3rd person close up — too close for comfort. A brain that has
>   been surgically divorced and lifted out of that body that had been
>   terminally ill, we will learn — an engineer who had been suffering
>   from radiation and had agreed to be used in a solar experiment —
>   though he is perhaps of hardly more than passing concern in a tale
>   whose growing is here and now under light which is alive in a capsule
>   with green growing things . A solar energy experiment that changes
>   unexpectedly.
>
> A brain hooked up to instruments and nutrients in a space capsule,
>   monitoring its physiological self, transmitting information along the
>   Concentration Loop to scientists on Earth, whom it knows only by sound
>   as the Good Voice, the Acrid Voice. Groping for words, memory, links,
>   a grasp of what is happening to it, the brain, this stunned thing,
>   begins to go beyond its assigned functions. It becomes more than IMP,
>   a NASA acronym for Interplanetary Monitoring Platform. It is Imp Plus.
>   Awakening, always awake, growing, we learn, not only as it relearns
>   words and itself, fragments of memories from its terrestrial life and
>   other data rich and fascinating, but growing a strange new body. When
>   it develops an autonomous intellect and effective life and cuts itself
>   off from ground control in the unraveling drama of this growth, what
>   can be its fate in collaboration with the sun and still more than the
>   sun?